# Can I apply a coupon/discount through the API to an order?

Tags: shopify

I would like to be able to apply a coupon/discount to an existing order through the API. Is that possible? I have checked the shopify API and did not see anything about that.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the order is placed it can't be edited. You can change fulfillment status, payment status, add notes, comments and even edit billing or shipping customer details but total order price, lines of the order or discounts can't be added or edited, to mention some.